# How can I set the size of Window fixed to its content in cocoa macOS?

Tags: swift, cocoa

There is a modifier called `windowResizability` in macOS SwiftUI which simply make the window be in the same size of its content like this code: `.windowResizability(.contentSize)` this code is for SwiftUI, I am looking the same effect in cocoa macOS-Storyboard.

Just need to know the needed code, thanks

Comment: The window is the same size as its content view, just add constraints, no code needed.

Comment: the window is going bigger than that it should be

Comment: Probably a missing constraint at the location of the extra space.